# SVG Displaying differently in firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

I am new to using svgs. The following displays perfectly in chrome but not in firefox

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 100 180" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 180" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
                                        <path d="M5.42,98.416c0,10.229,29.518,22.016,45.854,22.016c17.664,0,45.854-13.787,45.854-22.016H5.42z" />
                                        <path d="M49.063,95.832l0.062-66.375c-15.151,0-27.847,20.626-27.847,45.951c0,7.125,1.675,14.408,3.41,20.424H49.063z" />
                                        <path d="M51.668,95.887L51.612,4.096c18.097,0,32.768,28.354,32.768,63.33c0,9.842-2.1,20.16-4.172,28.469L51.668,95.887z" />
                                    </svg>
```

Is there something I can add to make it work in firefox?

Comment: Looks the same to me in Opera 12 and Firefox. What exactly is wrong with the Firefox rendering?

Comment: It is alot bigger than in chrome

Comment: You have not defined a `width` or a `height`, so there is no fixed size.  It should fill its container.